# Insert linebreak between authors

Tags: line-breaking, nameauth

For a publication, I am trying to follow [a template](http://www.iti.tugraz.at/EWSN2016/cms/fileadmin/user_upload/EWSN/Documents/ewsn-template.zip). The way of adding authors is the following in the template:

```
\documentclass[10pt,emptycopyrightspace]{ewsn-proc}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{comment}

\numberofauthors{2}

\author{
%
% The command \alignauthor (no curly braces needed) should
% precede each author name, affiliation/snail-mail address and
% e-mail address. Additionally, tag each line of
% affiliation/address with \affaddr, and tag the
%% e-mail address with \email.
\alignauthor Alice Security \\
        \affaddr{Department of Computer Science}\\
        \affaddr{University of Southern California}\\
       \email{alice@example.edu}
\alignauthor Bob Privacy \\
    \affaddr{Networked Embedded Systems Group}\\
    \affaddr{Swedish Institute of Computer Science}\\
    \email{bob@example.se}
}

\title{Full Paper}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}



\balance
\end{document}
```

My problem is, there are 5 authors, and I should add a linebreak between the 3rd and the 4th so that they fit in the page... Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This fragment of code isn't really useful. Please post a compilable document

Comment: A link to the template would be just as good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of `\alignauthor` is wrong, as it doesn't allow any break between authors.

```
\documentclass[10pt,emptycopyrightspace]{ewsn-proc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{comment}

\numberofauthors{5}

% Fix the bad definition of \alignauthor
\renewcommand\alignauthor{%
  \end{tabular}%
  \hspace{0pt}% <----- added
  \begin{tabular}[t]{p{\auwidth}}\centering
}


\author{
\alignauthor Alice Security \\
        \affaddr{Department of Computer Science}\\
        \affaddr{University of Southern California}\\
       \email{alice@example.edu}
\alignauthor Bob Privacy \\
    \affaddr{Networked Embedded Systems Group}\\
    \affaddr{Swedish Institute of Computer Science}\\
    \email{bob@example.se}
\alignauthor Alice Security \\
        \affaddr{Department of Computer Science}\\
        \affaddr{University of Southern California}\\
       \email{alice@example.edu}
\alignauthor Bob Privacy \\
    \affaddr{Networked Embedded Systems Group}\\
    \affaddr{Swedish Institute of Computer Science}\\
    \email{bob@example.se}
\alignauthor Bob Privacy \\
    \affaddr{Networked Embedded Systems Group}\\
    \affaddr{Swedish Institute of Computer Science}\\
    \email{bob@example.se}
}

\title{Full Paper for ACM EWSN Proceedings}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

%... The same as in the example file follows ...
```

[image]